# Flipping a plot 180 degrees in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if there is a way to **flip the below plot 180 degrees in R?**

```
par(pin=c(7,.5))

curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F)
axis(1, mgp=c(1, -.35, 0), tcl=F )
```

Comment: This is a "give me the code" type of question, and I would like to encourage you to show what you tried and describe what's not working with your attempt instead of requesting code.  When you ask questions here, you are expected to **show what you have tried to solve the problem** instead of only stating what your goal is and asking for code to help achieve it.

Comment: Can you narrow it  down - do you want to flip the line or have axes on the top (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BottomHalf = function(x) -dnorm(x)
curve(BottomHalf(x), -3, 3, bty="n", add=TRUE)
```

But you will need to allow the ylim to go negative.

```
curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, ylim=c(-0.41, 0.41))
curve(BottomHalf(x), -3, 3, bty="n", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it can be reduced to `curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3, bty="n", ann=F, axes=F, ylim=c(-0.41, 0.41)) ;
curve(-dnorm(x), add=TRUE)`